# Translate Transform and rotation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

the translate works fine, but there is no rotation, can you please help me?

```
TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();

Pointer.RenderTransform = trans;

DoubleAnimation animX = new DoubleAnimation(fromX, toX, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(325));
DoubleAnimation animY = new DoubleAnimation(fromY, toY, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(325));

DoubleAnimation rotateBy = new DoubleAnimation(0, 90, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(325));

animX.EasingFunction = new SineEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };
animY.EasingFunction = new SineEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };

animX.Completed += new EventHandler(myanim_Completed);
trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, animX);
trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, animY);

trans.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotateBy);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TranslateTransform` doesn't have an `Angle` property. You should use a `TransformGroup`:

```
var group = new TransformGroup();
var trans = new TranslateTransform();
group.Children.Add(trans);
var rotate = new RotateTransform();
group.Children.Add(rotate);

Pointer.RenderTransform = group;

// the rest of the code is fine; only the last line needs fixing:

rotate.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotateBy);
```

You should also look into using `Storyboard` to group your animations.